# Is there any way to convert phoneNumber +91-9999888877 (which is saved in column mob_number)

Tags: mysql

I want to convert this phone number into two columns.

1. country_code
2. mob_number

I am supposed to write a script in MYSQL so as to split and save this phone number into 2 columns of the same table in the database.

Example-> phone number (+91-9999888877 saved in column of `mob_number`) into column `country_code` as `91`, and into column `mob_number` as `9999888877` (note: the number of digits after the pincode can be 10 and 12) .

i tried this. thanks to @Tim
but it show an error . ( CHARINDEX doesnt exist)
[image]

Comment: Would _every_ number be in `+91-9999888877` format?

Comment: yes .@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: "I am supposed to write a script in SQL " - Ok, where's your attempt?

Comment: I am noob. and what i have tried , it show error of column mob_number doesnt exist. but column name is same. @MitchWheat

Comment: please update your question with that query

Comment: `I am supposed to write a script in MYSQL` then why do you have sql-server in your tags and not mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the base string functions here:

```sql
SELECT
    number,
    SUBSTRING(number, 2, CHARINDEX('-', number) - 2) AS code,
    SUBSTRING(number, CHARINDEX('-', number) + 1, LEN(number)) AS digits
FROM yourTable;
```